# multidimensional php array to js variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done something like so

PHP

```
 $returndata[$num] = array(
                        'type' => $num,
                        'id'=>$desc['id'],
                        'title' => $desc['title'],
                    );
    json_encode($returndata);
```

AJAX

```
success: function(data){
       var arr = data;
       for (i in arr)
            {
              console.log(arr[i].title);
            }
     }
```

ALSO Tried

```
success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, val){
                console.log(val.title);
            });  
         }
```

I have the following JSON that i would like to put in separate var to use in HTML.

```
{
 "5" :
      {
         "type":"5",
          "id":"590",
          "title":"Little Lamb"
      }
 "7" : 
      {
         "type" : "7",
         "id":"540",
         "title":"Little Lamb 2"
      }
}
```

But I can't get the titles.

Comment: set `dataType:'json'` in your ajax call, I think you are missing that

Comment: @PranavCBalan thanks for the heads up, i didn't know this is so important.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(key in data){
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        console.log(data[key].title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked after adding the dataType: 'json' as suggested by @Pranav C Balan in the comments.